# how to generate jks keystore file in databricks

Tags: keystore, databricks, jks

I am trying to follow this [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/security/encryption/encrypt-otw.html) in order to have data encryption at rest and transit(more [info](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html))

I am not able to get this step: 'The JKS keystore file used for enabling SSL/HTTPS is dynamically generated for each workspace. '

Where exactly is this jks keystore file generated in "dbfs:/" ?
Or do we have to manually generate this file? How to do so, any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files are automatically generated by databricks and are stored on the filesystem of the driver node, which is not part of the DBFS.

They are in the directory:
$DB_HOME/keys
($DB_HOME is an environment variable that points to the root dir for databricks on the driver. In my case it was "/databricks")

Comment: So is this $DB_HOME variable automatically set in each databricks job?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "in each databricks job". $DB_HOME is just a linux environment variable set on the driver node during cluster creation. ([link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-in-linux/))

Comment: What is the keystore_password, where to get this value & update